# Why does ruby need --enable-pthread in rvm for TK to run

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

What is really --enable-pthread ? and how does ruby use threads to work with tk.

Comment: Do you mean when compiling via `rvm install`?

Comment: Yes While compiling, i understand it is a compiler directive, but why do we need it in order to use TK, does it suddenly make ruby have multi-threaded support and why ? Isn't ruby normally not multi threaded ?

Comment: Also say which platform you're on, and which version of Tk. These matter.

Comment: I am on linux, On Mac i did n't even need to use pthread to use Tk .. but on linux i have to so whats the difference anmd whats happening ..?